# Numpy: Numerical integration with integration limits

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, integration

I have measured peaks that I want to integrate in a certain range.

The data I want to integrate is in the form of numpy arrays with wavenumbers and intensities:

```
peakQ1_2500_smoothened =
array([[ 1.95594400e+04, -3.70074342e-17,  3.26000000e+00],
       [ 1.95594500e+04,  1.66666667e-03,  4.81500000e+00],
       [ 1.95594600e+04,  2.83333333e-02,  4.80833333e+00],
       [ 1.95594700e+04,  1.33333333e-02,  4.82166667e+00],
       [ 1.95594800e+04,  5.00000000e-03,  4.92416667e+00],
       [ 1.95594900e+04,  5.55555556e-04,  4.99305556e+00],
       [ 1.95595100e+04, -7.77777778e-03,  5.03972222e+00],
       [ 1.95595200e+04, -5.55555556e-03,  4.96888889e+00],
       [ 1.95595300e+04, -1.77777778e-02,  4.91333333e+00],
       [ 1.95595400e+04,  1.38888889e-02,  4.82500000e+00],
       [ 1.95595500e+04,  7.05555556e-02,  4.85722222e+00],
       [ 1.95595600e+04,  1.43888889e-01,  4.86638889e+00],
       [ 1.95595700e+04,  1.98888889e-01,  4.85138889e+00],
       [ 1.95595800e+04,  2.84444444e-01,  4.90694444e+00],
       [ 1.95595900e+04,  4.64444444e-01,  4.93611111e+00],
       [ 1.95596000e+04,  6.61111111e-01,  4.98166667e+00],
       [ 1.95596100e+04,  9.61666667e-01,  4.96722222e+00],
       [ 1.95596200e+04,  1.23222222e+00,  4.94388889e+00],
       [ 1.95596400e+04,  1.43555556e+00,  5.02166667e+00],
       [ 1.95596500e+04,  1.53222222e+00,  5.00500000e+00],
       [ 1.95596600e+04,  1.59833333e+00,  5.03666667e+00],
       [ 1.95596700e+04,  1.66388889e+00,  4.94555556e+00],
       [ 1.95596800e+04,  1.60111111e+00,  4.92777778e+00],
       [ 1.95596900e+04,  1.42333333e+00,  4.94666667e+00],
       [ 1.95597000e+04,  1.14111111e+00,  5.00777778e+00],
       [ 1.95597100e+04,  9.52222222e-01,  5.08555556e+00],
       [ 1.95597200e+04,  7.25555556e-01,  5.09222222e+00],
       [ 1.95597300e+04,  5.80555556e-01,  5.08055556e+00],
       [ 1.95597400e+04,  3.92777778e-01,  5.09611111e+00],
       [ 1.95597500e+04,  2.43222222e-01,  5.01655556e+00],
       [ 1.95597600e+04,  1.36555556e-01,  4.99822222e+00],
       [ 1.95597700e+04,  6.32222222e-02,  4.87044444e+00],
       [ 1.95597800e+04,  3.88888889e-02,  4.91944444e+00],
       [ 1.95597900e+04,  3.22222222e-02,  4.93611111e+00],
       [ 1.95598000e+04,  2.44444444e-02,  5.10277778e+00],
       [ 1.95598100e+04,  5.11111111e-02,  5.11277778e+00],
       [ 1.95598200e+04,  4.44444444e-02,  5.21944444e+00],
       [ 1.95598300e+04,  4.33333333e-02,  5.05333333e+00],
       [ 1.95598400e+04,  3.58333333e-02,  5.08750000e+00],
       [ 1.95598500e+04,  7.50000000e-03,  5.12750000e+00],
       [ 1.95598600e+04,  4.16666667e-03,  5.22916667e+00],
       [ 1.95598800e+04, -1.33333333e-02,  3.51000000e+00]])
```

[image]

I found that I can do an integration over the whole array with:

```
def integratePeak(yvals, xvals):
    I = np.trapz(yvals, x = xvals)
    return I
```

But how do I make an integration with x-limits, for example from 19559.52 to 19559.78?

```
def integratePeak(yvals, xvals, xlower, xupper):
    '''integrate y over x from xlower to xupper'''
    return I
```

I could of course give the x- and y-values by explicitly referring to array elements as `peakQ1_2500_smoothened[7:33,0]` and `peakQ1_2500_smoothened[7:33,1]` but obviously I do not want to refer to array elements but define the integration limits as wavenumbers because the different measured peaks have different array lengths.

---

Functions for reducing to one data point per wavenumber and then taking a running average:

```
def averagePerWavenumber(data):
    wavenum, intensity, power = data[:,0], data[:,1], data[:,2]
    wavenum_unique, intensity_mean = npi.group_by(wavenum).mean(intensity)
    wavenum_unique, power_mean = npi.group_by(wavenum).mean(power)
    output = np.zeros(shape=(len(wavenum_unique), 3))
    output[:,0] = wavenum_unique
    output[:,1] = intensity_mean
    output[:,2] = power_mean
    return output

def smoothening(data, bins):
    output = np.zeros(shape=(len(data[:,0]), 3))
    output[:,0] = data[:,0]
    output[:,1] = np.convolve(data[:,1], np.ones(bins), mode='same') / bins
    output[:,2] = np.convolve(data[:,2], np.ones(bins), mode='same') / bins
    return output
```

Comment: can you please post the array as text instead of a photo?  Also, how did you smooth it?

Comment: Do `peakQ1_2500_smoothened[7:33,0] and peakQ1_2500_smoothened[7:33,1]` with a variable `peakQ1_2500_smoothened[start:end, 0]`.

Comment: @InyoungKim  The point is that I want to give the integration limits as wavenumbers (my x-axis) and not as the number that value is in the array. Because a certain x-value is not always the same position in the array.
I would have assumed that is something very common to do.

Comment: @anon01  Added the array. I made a function to have only one data point per wavenumber and another function to then take a running average over the data points. I also added these. Though this is not relevant for the problem: How to make a numerical integration with integration limits.

Comment: Find the indices of the points you want to integrate between, and integrate the appropriate slice.

Comment: Please see the edit I made. That's how you should post data. Don't retain bad content. Just because you wrote something down does not make it valuable.

Comment: I don't know why you added those two functions at the end...

Comment: Ok, sorry, I thought the data is not needed as code and only for illustration of the problem. The two functions at the end are completely irrelevant to the problem but I was asked how I did the smoothening, that's why I added them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's start by looking at what [`np.trapz`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.trapz.html) actually does. The area of the `i`th trapezoid is the average height times the width: `0.5 * (y[i + 1] + y[i]) * (x[i + 1] - x[i])`. If you have a fixed `dx` instead of an `x` array, the last term is just a scalar. So let's rewrite your first function:

```
def integrate_peak0(y, x):
    """ x can be array of same size as y or a scalar """
    dx = x if x.size <= 1 else np.diff(x)
    return np.sum(0.5 * (y[1:] + y[:-1]) * dx)
```

The hardest part now is interpolating the limits of integration. Since `x` is sorted, you can use [`np.searchsorted`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) to convert the limits into indices into data:

```
limits = np.array([xlower, xupper])
indices = np.searchsorted(x, limits)
```

If the limits always fall on exact values of `x`, you can use `indices` directly:

```
def integrate_peak1(y, x, xlower, xupper):
    indices = np.searchsorted(x, [xlower, xupper])
    s = slice(indices[0], indices[1] + 1)
    return np.trapz(y[s], x[s])
```

Since this will almost never be the case, you can try the next simplest approach: rounding to the nearest value. You can use fancy indexing to get a 2D array for each potential bound that you can apply [`np.argmin`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argmin.html) to:

```
candidates = x[np.stack((indices - 1, indices), axis=0)]
offset = np.abs(candidates - limits).argmin(axis=0) - 1
indices += offset
```

`candidates` is a 2x2 array with the columns representing the candiates for each bound, and the rows representing the lesser and greater candidate. `offset` will be the amount that you need to modify the index by to get the nearest neighbor. Here is a version of the integrator that selects the nearest bin based on the integration limits:

```
def integrate_peak2(y, x, xlower, xupper):
    limits = np.array([xlower, xupper])
    indices = np.searchsorted(x, limits)
    candidates = x[np.stack((indices - 1, indices), axis=0)]
    indices += np.abs(candidates - limits).argmin(axis=0) - 1

    s = slice(indices[0], indices[1] + 1)
    return np.trapz(y[s], x[s])
```

The final version is to interpolate the values of `y` based on `x`. This version can be implemented in one of two ways. You can either compute the target y-values and pass them to `np.trapz` with the appropriate `x`, or you can use the function defined in `integrate_peak0` to do the operation yourself.

Given an element `x[i] < xn <= x[i + 1]`, you can estimate `yn = y[i] + (y[i + 1] - y[i]) * (x[n] - x[i]) / (x[i + 1] - x[i])`. Here, `x[i]` and `x[i + 1]` are the values of `candidates` shown above. `y[i]` and `y[i + 1]` are the corresponding elements of `y`. `xn` is `limits`. So you can compute the interpolation in a couple of different ways.

One way is to adjust the inputs to `trapz`:

```
def integrate_peak3a(y, x, xlower, xupper):
    limits = np.array([xlower, xupper])
    indices = np.searchsorted(x, limits)
    indices = np.stack((indices - 1, indices), axis=0)
    xi = x[indices]
    yi = y[indices]
    yn = yi[0] + np.diff(yi, axis=0) * (limits - xi[0]) / np.diff(xi, axis=0)

    indices = indices[[1, 0], [0, 1]]
    s = slice(indices[0], indices[1] + 1)
    return np.trapz(np.r_[yn[0, 0], y[s], yn[0, 1]], np.r_[xlower, x[s], xupper])
```

Another way is to compute the sums of the edge fragments manually:

```
def integrate_peak3b(y, x, xlower, xupper):
    limits = np.array([xlower, xupper])
    indices = np.searchsorted(x, limits)
    indices = np.stack((indices - 1, indices), axis=0)
    xi = x[indices]
    yi = y[indices]
    yn = yi[0] + np.diff(yi, axis=0) * (limits - xi[0]) / np.diff(xi, axis=0)

    indices = indices[[1, 0], [0, 1]]
    s = slice(indices[0], indices[1] + 1)
    return np.trapz(y[s], x[s]) - 0.5 * np.diff((yn + y[indices]) * (x[indices] - limits))
```

And of course, you can run the inputs to `np.trapz` in `integrate_peak3a` through the "manual" calculation in `integrate_peak0`.

Checking that the limits of integration are within an acceptable range and in the right order is left as an exercise for the reader in all these cases.

Comment: Thank you for the thorough explanation. Using the indices directly is sufficient because it is ok to just use the closest value and since I am using a running average before integrating there will always be the exact value So, all I really needed was either `np.searchsorted` or `np.argmin()`. I tried googling all possible phrasings of "numpy numerical integration with limits" and strangely did not find anything useful. All I found was either integrating with specific indices or analytical integration with functions.

Comment: @Wulfram. I wasn't sure which situation applied to you, so I gave you all the options. It's not too bad once you know what tools are out there. Also, just as an FYI, none of the code here is tested :)

Answer (score 1):

```
def integratePeak(yvals, xvals, xlower, xupper):
    '''integrate y over x from xlower to xupper.

    Use trapz to integrate over points closest to xlower, xupper.
    
    the +1 to idx_max is for numpy half-open indexing.
    '''
    idx_min = np.argmin(np.abs(xvals - xlower))
    idx_max = np.argmin(np.abs(xvals - xupper)) + 1
    result = np.trapz(yvals[idx_min:idx_max], x=xvals[idx_min:idx_max])
    return result
```

As an aside, you may benefit from using pandas for tabular data - it interoperates well with numpy arrays and most importantly lets you label your data:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(peakQ1_2500_smoothened, columns=["wave_num", "intensity", "col3"])

integratePeak(yvals=df.intensity, xvals=df.wave_num, xlower=19559.52, xupper=19559.78)

# 0.18853555549577536
```

Comment: Thank you. I know about Pandas but did not yet take the time to get into it and sticked with numpy so far. Strangely, when I googled for "numpy numerical integration with limits" there was no single useful answer making use of `np.argmin()` or `np.searchsorted()` despite this being one of the most common things people do.

Comment: @Wulfram sure.  As a side comment: the error in your integrated value looks to be dominated first by your sample data, then maybe your smoothing technique.  Until those are improved, I would not complicate the integration algorithm for performance or accuracy.